# Default to a typeclass when a data type does not instantiate it

Tags: haskell

Imagine that we are defining a custom `Display` typeclass that acts like `Show` but with a prettier formatting:

```
class Display a where
    display :: a -> PrettyFormat
```

Would it be possible to make a simple function `prettyPrint` that calls `display` if the `Display` type class is instantiated for the data type, and `show` if it's not?

Comment: This can only work if the compiler compiles the whole program and libraries in a single gulp, or forbidding orphan instances. Incremental compilation pretty much copes with that, since the compiler does not know if another module will define a `Display` instance.

Comment: I reckon the best way to convince you _not_ to try this is to show you [what it involves](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap). And even that solution suffers from a couple really unpleasant problems.

Comment: @Alec any idea so it doesn't involve instantiating my typeclass for each Haskell type?

Comment: @NikitaTchayka The best approach (which I would've suggested if this question had not been closed) is to make a `default` signature for `Display` with a `Show` constraint. Then, if you automatically derive `Display` you end up with the `Show` variant, but you can still customize the output with hand written `Display` variants if you want.